# Set scroll position back after changing element position fixed and unfixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a JSBin with a page, and a functional sliding nav. The only thing wrong with it is that it resets the scroll position when I open the side navigation. I use a jquery click event to toggle the nav and move the page to the side. When it moves the page over, it sets the position fixed, and moves it over 200 px. I have tried to use jquery to record the scroll position before the nav is toggled, and set it back when it isn't fixed, but after trying to use other examples, they won't work. I don't know if there is something wrong with my script, or I could use css another way.

The JSBin is [here](http://jsbin.com/voresu/30/edit?)

I would like to not introduce anything but html, css, js, or jquery in the answer.

Comment: And your code is? ... and the question is?

Comment: Read this, http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and then update your question

Comment: accidentaly submitted before finishing typing the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

Javascript:

```
$('.c-hamburger').click(function(){
    if($('.nav').css('width') == '0px'){
        $('.nav').css('width', '200px');
        $('.body').css('margin-left', '200px');
    }else{
        $('.nav').css('width', '0px');
        $('.body').css('margin-left', '0px');
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
.nav{
    width: 0px;
    transition: width 0.5s;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.body{
    transition: margin-left 0.5s;
}
center{
    min-width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: I didn't think to use margin! Thanks a lot! I'm going to disable horizontal scrolling, because that looks bad. I'm also going to integrate it with the code I already have.